# How to work with dynamic variable in file chef resource?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo, aws-opsworks

When we work with template chef resource, then `<%= node["fqdn"] %>` will modify with node's fqdn. I want to do this using file resource. I have a file `abc.txt` and `<%= node["fqdn"] %>` or any other variable inside it.
How to change this variable with actual value when chef-client runs.

This is my file resource -->

```
file "/home/user/test.txt" do
  content IO.read("/opt/cheftest/abc.txt")
  mode '0755'
  action :create
end
```

Above copies content of abc.txt in test.txt as it is without changing variable name with actual values. How to change variables with actual values ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are asking for is the [`local` property on the `template` resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_template.html#properties), but it is hard to tell. Normally you would just use a plain old `template` resource unless you have a really good reason.

Comment: I am trying to set local property and this gives me following error ->
Option local must be a kind of [TrueClass, FalseClass]!  You passed :true.

Comment: can we fetch AWS tags of a node using chef ?

Comment: The values `true` and `:true` are not the same. The first is a boolean, the second is a symbol. As for tags, they are not available via the EC2 metadata system so they are not loaded via ohai. You could use the EC2 API itself via IAM roles but that is both an advanced thing and has potentially troubling security consequences.

Comment: Thanks, I have one more confusion, this is not related to this question. when we register a ec2 instance with AWS Opswork ,then on "Step 3: Install AWS CLI" ,there are two options in installation type ->Installation type
1. Run the register command from a separate workstation
2. Run the command from the instance to be imported
What is significant of these two option ?

Comment: Please don't ask unrelated things in a comment, it makes it difficult to follow. Create a new question if you must.